# Weird situation where useState works sometimes and it does not works sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am using hooks in react native, setState works sometimes and doesnot work sometimes. The code I am sharing is to increment count when it reaches the end of flatlist. The hook I added for count prints incremented value but when I use it somewhere it always uses 10.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default Trending = (props) => {

   const [count, setCount] = useState(10);

   function showMore() {
        setLoading(true);
        setCount(count + 10);
        getRecentlyAdded();
    }

    async function getRecentlyAdded() {
      try {
        console.log(count); //always prints 10
      } catch (e) {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }

       <FlatList
                data={dataList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <SwipeList goToDetailed={goToDetailedPageClick} item={item} />}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                initialNumToRender={10}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.3}
                onEndReached={() => {
                    showMore();
                }}
            />

}
```

It always prints 10 in console and value never gets updated.

I added a hook to check value of count

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(count); //prints incremented but still uses 10
    }, [count])
```

Comment: I don't think you can rely on that value, as it's coming from the closure. What if you move the console.log *outside* the showMore function, so it's called on every render? setState will trigger a re-render with the new state.

Comment: FlatList doesn't use count...

Answer (score -1):

If value of the state remains the same, then `setState` or `useState` won't update or render. Hope this gave you a little hint.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, the count is incremented, so I don't think state remaining the same is the problem here. The person asks why the the state _change_ isn't reflected where it is used. This implies that there is a change.

Comment: Hi Sorry, Actually you need to use a callback for state change to get reflected immediately because state update can take sometime. You can use useEffect() hook in your component and resolved my use-case.